# Detect an application is installed or not?

Tags: android

I have a application that registers a handler for custom URI on the Phone. I am able to launch the application by making a link to "myapp://act/launch" from my phone web pages. This works only if my application is installed on the device. 
What I want to do is detect if the URI Scheme is supported from the browser and then prompt my own message saying "please download the app etc..." if the handler for the URI scheme is not found.

Is there a way I can detect or find the list of URL Scheme handlers on the Phone from the Web Browser ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if application is installed - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)

Comment: check this answer, it support all version https://stackoverflow.com/a/72014352/4797289

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From [Android How-to's](http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/detect-if-an-app-is-installed)

> If you ever need to know if a particular app is installed on the user's device, you can use the PackageManager.  From a Context class (e.g. an Activity or a Service) you can call getPackageManager().  This gives you a variety of methods, one of which is getPackageInfo().  Below is a method you might use.  You might call it like this:

```
isAppInstalled("com.simexusa.campusmaps_full");

private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
       pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
       installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

Comment: Regardless: is "uri" a proper argument name to the method? Would packageName be better?

Comment: @GlennBech: yes, _packageName_ is more descriptive than _uri_

Comment: But this answer isn't for question above. It more like "determine whether particular application is installed from another application" (but not from Web Browser)

Comment: Agree with the above plus he specifically asked about URI schema. Which is what I am looking for. Is there a way to determine if the URI schema exist on the phone or is it mandatory to use package name ?

Answer (score 15):

1. You need to create a web page that user lands on if the app is not 
   installed. Say http://www.yourcompany.com/android/android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html
2. The app needs to register in manifest XML file host www.yourcompany.com, 
   schema “http” and the path param to app not install landing page in 
   the manifest intent filter:

   ```
   <!-- These intents are used to launch the app from the web page-->
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="http"
           android:host="www.yourcompany.com"
           android:path="/android/android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html" 
     />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
3. Now in the web page that invokes your app you specify full link to 
   android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html followed by whatever 
   params you want to pass to the app:

http://www.yourcompany.com/android/ 
android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html? 
'>Click here to launch 
the app if it is installed

If the app is installed it will be launched and passed entire 
http://www.yourcompany.com/android/android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html?' 
in intent that it needs to parse, extract the 
 and do whatever it is 
supposed to do.

If the app is not installed, then the Android Web browser will open 
“Android app not installed” landing page 
http://www.yourcompany.com/android/android_app_is_not_installed_landing_page.html o
. That page should message user to install the app and provide the 
link to install it from Android marketplace.

found this write up here: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/RGLHkGUpRoA

Comment: So why the drive by downvote, since it actually answers the question he was asking?

Answer (score 1):

In my custom **Helper.java**

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context context, String packageName)
{
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Tag",packageName + " not installed");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call it by

```
Helper.isPackageInstalled(yourActivity.this,"app_package_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is correct, but those who are looking for Kotlin solution can use this method,

Here I have written an article. [Check If Application is Installed in Android Kotlin](https://handyopinion.com/check-if-application-is-installed-in-android-kotlin/)

```
fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String, context: Context): Boolean {
        return try {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
            true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            false
        }
    }
```