# How to read other app's SharedPreferences (same user ID)?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Tested on Android 4.3. I have two apps, `com.my.app.first` and `com.my.app.second`. In my activity I want to read preferences from the other app. I chose to use the same user ID for both my apps:

`android:sharedUserId="com.my.app"`

I always load my preferences like this:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now, in my **second app** I do the following:

```
try {
    Context context = createPackageContext("com.my.app.first", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    // context.getPackageName() does indeed return "com.my.app.first"

    // Note: Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE makes no difference here!
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

`prefs.mFile` erroneously points to `/data/data/com.my.app.second/shared_prefs/MyAppPreferences.xml`.

Obviously, the call to [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) returns the **preferences for the current app even though I used the context of the other app**. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: in the app that you create the SharedPrefs do you set the mode as MODE_WORLD_READABLE ?

Comment: Nope. And it's not needed since the same `sharedUserId` is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem! This sure looks like a bug in the `getSharedPreferences` API. It turned out that a *previous* call to `getSharedPreferences` caused the other `context.getSharedPreferences()` call to return the previous instance - the current app's preferences.

The solution was to make sure that `getSharedPreferences()` was **NOT** called before reading the preferences of the other app.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by just reading the old context again. Sounds like a cache to me too.

```
Context tempContext = context.createPackageContext(originalContext.getPackageName(),Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences sharedInformationM2 = tempContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedInformation", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: Doesn't work me, same issue with this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make the SharedPreference created in App A MODE_WORLD_READABLE and use a common sharedUserId for both App A and App B. Like mentioned in the link,

http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` make the preferences readably by *all* apps? I thought the purpose of `sharedUserId` was to allow reading private data.

Comment: This is what the documentation says about `MODE_PRIVATE`: *File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).* That's why I posted my question.

Comment: Right MODE_WORLD_READABLE makes it read-able all the applications, by nature, and my bad about sharedUserId, instead what i meant was use a unique name while calling like context.getSharedPreference("unique", MODE).  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: you have said you are using prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) here, with Desired Name as MyAppPreference, this will result in system creating a new shared preference file for this app. ideally it should be the same as what the other applicatin uses while creating.

Comment: I googled this, and a few sources show my code snippet. Will it create a new file even though I'm using the other app's context? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since both your apps are running you can also solve this problem by setting shared preferences:

```
tempContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedInformation", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```