# How can I check whether an app is installed

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I check whether an app is installed with getPackageManager?
I have no idea. Thanks.
Android.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("PACKAGE_NAME", "PACKAGE_NAME.TARGET_ACTIVITY");
    if (isCallable(context, intent)) {
        // Attach any extras, start or start with callback
    } else {
        // Respond to the application or activity not being available
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking for what the method body for `isCallable` should be?

Comment: This question [has been asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android/18752247#18752247)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
        Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
        if (mIntent != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of installed apps by using the below code snippet

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
  List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
```

Now you can get package name for each installed app, and then can perform a check for package name

```
ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
String packageName = data.packageName;
```

Checkout another example [How to Get List of Installed Apps in Android](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I think [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is more appropriet since you have a target activity defined in your intent. If the list return is of `.size() == 0`. Then it's safe to say it's not available.

```
protected boolean isCallable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return activities.size() > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private boolean appInstalledorNot(String packageName) {
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean app_installed = false;
try {
    pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    app_installed = true;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    app_installed = false;
}
return app_installed;
}
```