# When you use Intent.ACTION_DELETE, how can you tell if the user actually uninstalls the app?

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-package-managers

This is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + theApp.getAppOpen()));
startActivity(intent);
```

When startActivity is called, a default prompt comes up, asking the user whether they want to uninstall that app.

How can I tell if the user says "ok" to uninstall the app?
Assume my app is not the one being uninstalled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options, and you might want to use a combination of the two:

1) Register a `BroadcastReceiver` for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED), and once fired, you can inspect the `data` of the intent to see whether *your* package was removed. It might be wise to add a time-out of sorts, possibly through an Alarm set five minutes into the future.

2) Once the user returns from either uninstalling or canceling the uninstall, your Activity will resume. You can check whether the package of interest still exists in `onResume()`, using [`PackageManager.getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) or similar. Note: The user might not return to your app, in which case the time-out/Alarm recommendation would become important.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. The second way was what I was interested in. But, what do you mean by the "time-out/Alarm recommendation"?

Comment: I was referring to the last line in the first option -- setting an Alarm five minutes into the future to check whether an app was actually uninstalled -- since you may not see the resume for a while if the user doesn't return; or you may not see it at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the "[**ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE)" intent (API 14 and above) so that you could check if the uninstallation has succeeded or not.

docs say:

> Activity Action: Launch application uninstaller.
>
> Input: The data must be a package: URI whose scheme specific part is
>   the package name of the current installed package to be uninstalled.
>   You can optionally supply EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT.
>
> Output: If EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, returns whether the install succeeded.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE"

Comment: Best for me but requires permission: android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but you can use `startActivityForResult(removeIntent, 0)`
as a first step and then after taking any action - whether it's uninstalled or not - `onActivityResult` method is called, so, for a second step you can check in `onActivityResult` whether this app now exists or not. Follow this for more details of the second step:
[[Check if application is installed - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android][1])