# Unable to open Linkedin profile using intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

How to open linkedin profile using intent :

My code :

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(APP_PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("linkedin://profile/" + profileID));
intent.setPackage(APP_PACKAGE_NAME);
// intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Log:

```
12-10 19:18:49.363     936-2104/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=linkedin://profile/132778900 pkg=com.linkedin.android cmp=com.linkedin.android/.infra.deeplink.DeepLinkHelperActivity} from pid 8392
12-10 19:18:49.373    1223-1377/? E/﹕ no predefined limited group find for com.linkedin.android, add to foreground group
12-10 19:18:49.463    7964-7964/? I/CrashReporter﹕ Starting activity DeepLinkHelperActivity Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=linkedin://profile/132778900 pkg=com.linkedin.android cmp=com.linkedin.android/.infra.deeplink.DeepLinkHelperActivity }
12-10 19:18:49.493    7964-7964/? E/com.linkedin.android.deeplink.helper.LaunchHelper﹕ urlParams was null, indicating a failure to validate the path in getMap()
12-10 19:18:59.523    7964-7996/? D/LinkedInNetwork﹕ Performing request
12-10 19:19:04.573    1619-1666/? I/XiaomiFirewall﹕ firewall pkgName:com.linkedin.android, result:0
```

Comment: When you say 'Open linked in profile', where and how exactly are you opening it?

Comment: method is in another class in which I write code open linkedin profile and I am calling that method on click

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but are you trying to pass a url along with the intent?

Comment: means? I am not getting what are you saying

Comment: I have posted whatever I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the latest [documentation from LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk), you should be using the `DeepLinkHelper` to integrate deep-linking with the official app:

```
// Get a reference to an activity to return the user to
final Activity thisActivity = this;

// A sample member ID value to open
final String targetID = "abcd1234";

DeepLinkHelper deepLinkHelper = DeepLinkHelper.getInstance();

// Open the target LinkedIn member's profile
deepLinkHelper.openOtherProfile(thisActivity, targetID, new DeeplinkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkSuccess() {
        // Successfully sent user to LinkedIn app
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkError(LiDeepLinkError error) {
        // Error sending user to LinkedIn app
    }
});
```

Or prefer the following to open the profile of the currently authenticated user:

```
// Get a reference to an activity to return the user to
final Activity thisActivity = this;

DeepLinkHelper deepLinkHelper = DeepLinkHelper.getInstance();

// Open the current user's profile
deepLinkHelper.openCurrentProfile(thisActivity, new DeeplinkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkSuccess() {
        // Successfully sent user to LinkedIn app
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkError(LiDeepLinkError error) {
        // Error sending user to LinkedIn app
    }
});
```

Either way, if dive into the [implementation of the `DeepLinkHelper`](https://github.com/tuandnse02939/ConnectLinked/blob/master/linkedin-sdk/src/main/java/com/linkedin/platform/DeepLinkHelper.java#L73), you'll see that it ends up constructing the `Intent` that opens the LinkedIn app like this:

```
private void deepLinkToProfile(@NonNull Activity activity, String memberId, @NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.scheme("linkedin");
    if (CURRENTLY_LOGGED_IN_MEMBER.equals(memberId)) {
        uriBuilder.authority(CURRENTLY_LOGGED_IN_MEMBER);
    } else {
        uriBuilder.authority("profile").appendPath(memberId);
    }
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("accessToken", accessToken.getValue());
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("src", "sdk");
    i.setData(uriBuilder.build());
    Log.i("Url: ", uriBuilder.build().toString());
    activity.startActivityForResult(i, LI_SDK_CROSSLINK_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

As you can see, amongst other things, it attaches the access token to the `Uri` as a query parameter with key `accessToken`. The other query parameter that gets added is `src`, which (presumably) is just used for statistical purposes and not something functional.

Now, if you look at this particular line in your error log:

```
E/com.linkedin.android.deeplink.helper.LaunchHelper﹕ urlParams was null, indicating a failure to validate the path in getMap()
```

Note:

> urlParams was null

That sounds to me like it is expecting one ore more query parameters for the data `Uri`. I'm inclined to say that that is most likely referring to (at least) the `accessToken` query parameter that is missing in your own code snippet, yet is part of the SDK flow.

Hopefully that's a push in the right direction. It might be easiest to just use the LinkedIn SDK - any particular reason you aren't?

Comment: So now you have a different problem? Looks like you may have to go through an [authorisation flow](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) first (in particular, read the bits down the bottom). Could you also please update your question with what you currently have, or start a new question if your code has fundamentally changed?

Answer (score 6):

```
public void openLinkedInPage(String linkedId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("linkedin://add/%@" + linkedId));
        final PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=" + linkedId));
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.parse("linkedin://you"));
 final PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.isEmpty()) {
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=you"));
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string PACKAGE = "com.linkedin.android";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse("https://www.linkedin.com/in/danielroberts0"));
if(isPackageInstalled(Forms.Context, PACKAGE)) {
    intent.SetPackage(PACKAGE);
}
Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

None of the solutions provided what I needed - opening a users profile page in the app. by default or website otherwise.

Ref:
[Check if application is installed - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will open LinkedIn Profile in app, or open in browser if LinkedIn app is not Installed (works as of Nov 2018, with latest Version LinkedIn App), no need to use `DeepLinkHelper`

```
        String profile_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/syedfaisal33";
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(profile_url));
            intent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(profile_url)));
        }
```

Comment: and if you want to choose between LinkedIn app and browser, use this code instead of the 3rd line, `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("linkedin://syedfaisal33"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getOpenLinkedin(context: Context, url: String) {
    val linkedinIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    linkedinIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android", "com.linkedin.android.profile.ViewProfileActivity")
    linkedinIntent.putExtra("memberId", "profile")
    linkedinIntent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android")
    try {
        context.startActivity(linkedinIntent)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
    }
}
```