# How to check Whatsapp is installed in device in android?

Tags: android

I want to check that whether whatsapp is installed in mobile or not if installed then show toast "installed" and if not installed then show Toast "Not Installed".How can I do that Kindly help.

Comment: search by its package name using package manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if application is installed - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use this code. It will check if package is installed.

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Put the package name here...
        if(isAppInstalled("com.whatsapp")) {
            System.out.println("App is already installed on your phone");         
        } else {
            System.out.println("App is not currently installed on your phone");
        }
    }

    private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
        try {
            getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned by @Sattar, it is imperative to update your manifest file when working with Android 11.

```
<manifest ...> 
 <queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
  </queries>
  <application ....>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: after android 11 you also need this under manifest                                                                      <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    </queries>

Comment: i tried this but in Redem note 10 pro max with andriod 11 it goes to catch and the only error message i get is "com.whatsapp". has there some thing changed?

Answer (score 9):

based on @eliasz-kubala answer this will work for me on Android 11 after only adding this to Manifest

```
  <manifest 
    ...> 
    <queries> <package android:name="com.whatsapp" /> </queries>
  
    <application ....>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

and Then use this Kotlin function

```
  private fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String): Boolean {
    val pm: PackageManager = getPackageManager()
    return try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
   }
```

Comment: would love to know what's the reason for this. What does query exactly do? And why do we need it. Btw thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to get all package names of installed applications in device

```
 final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

after getting list of packages search for com.whatsapp(package name of whats app given on official webiste [Whatsapp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)). Thats it..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

Here you need to pass package name as uri.

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
```

**Check condition like this.**

```
if(!appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")){
    // Toast message not installed.
}else{
    // Toast message installed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public class WhatsApp_Check extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("whatsapp_package_name");  
        if(installed) {
          //print whatsApp is already installed on your phone
            else{
           // print whatsApp is not currently installed on your phone
        }
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
private void checkWhatsapp() {
    String packageName = "com.whatsapp";
    String mesgToShare = "Hey, I am searching for Whatsapp in your device.";

    boolean gotPackage = false;
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND );
    shareIntent.setType( "text/plain" );
    shareIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mesgToShare );
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( shareIntent, 0 );
    for ( final ResolveInfo app : activityList ) {
        if ( (app.activityInfo.name).contains( packageName ) ) {
            gotPackage = true;
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName( activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name );
            shareIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
            shareIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );
            shareIntent.setComponent( name );
            startActivity( shareIntent );
            break; // We already found what we were looking for. Don't need to execute the rest of the Loop
        }
    }

    if ( !gotPackage )
        Log.e("TAG", "Whatsapp is not installed in your device");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (isAppInstalled("com.whatsapp")) {
            val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
            sendIntent.component = ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation")
            sendIntent.putExtra(
                "jid",
                PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("918219243720").toString() + "@s.whatsapp.net"
            )

            startActivity(sendIntent)

        } else {
            showToast("App is not currently installed on your phone")
        }
```

Now Create fun()

```
private fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)

        true
    } catch (ignored: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}
```

Now Add same lines in Manifest file

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
</queries>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are problematic. Please [edit] to explain what this code does, and what (if anything) it does better than the multiple previous answers from several years back.