# check if multiple application is installed or not

Tags: java, android

I want to check if multiple application is installed or not in user device and always get toast Application is not currently installed but whatsapp and instagram is installed. why?

```
  String [] strings = new String [] {"com.whatsapp", "com.android.instagram" };
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings)); 



        boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot(String.valueOf(stringList));
        if(isAppInstalled) {

            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(String.valueOf(stringList));startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Application is already installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Application is not currently installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by if "multiple application" is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameter. Try something like below.

```
 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}

public void check(){
String [] strings = new String [] {"com.whatsapp", "com.android.instagram" };
for(String appPackageName: strings) {
    boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot(appPackageName);
    if(isAppInstalled) {
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,appPackageName+" is already installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,appPackageName+" is not currently installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Note:- Do not fire `LaunchIntent`inside loop . first check which applications are installed and then you can select from list(As per your need cause i have no knowledge of it).

Or you can directly check for each one separately:

```
 boolean isWhatsAppinstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");
 boolean isInstainstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.android.instagram");
```

Comment: this code give all toast "is already installed." and "is not currently installed" than close app :(

Comment: Yeah i will give all . I just pointed out your mistake . I am not aware  of what exactly your need is .

Answer (score 0):

Since you copy pasted this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36419540/4467208 you should actually also modify it to your needs. You can not pass your String concatenation to `appInstalledOrNot` since it does not support it whatsoever.

Instead change it to

```
boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp") && appInstalledOrNot("com.android.instagram");
```

If you want to show different Toasts for different cases then you have to call `appInstalledOrNot` one by one.