# How to check if WhatsApp is installed on device?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, whatsapp

```
Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?phone=${phoneNumber}`);
```

The above code will navigate to WhatsApp however I'm wondering if it's possible to check existence of WhatsApp before trying to `openURL`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419423/how-to-check-whatsapp-is-installed-in-device-in-android

Comment: @MiguelRocha: I do aware of the link but it's in Android not RN

Comment: check in package manager list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)

Comment: Can you try using Linking.canOpenURL()? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#canopenurl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#opening-external-links):

> To start the corresponding activity for a link (web URL, email, contact etc.), call
>
> ```
> Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
> ```
>
> If you want to check if any installed app can handle a given URL beforehand you can call
>
> ```
> Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
>   if (!supported) {
>     console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
>   } else {
>     return Linking.openURL(url);
>   }
> }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
> ```

I assume, if WhatsApp is not installed, the `!supported` block will be invoked and you can do your computation there.

Answer (score 2):

It can be checked using the PackageManager. Just iterate over the installed packages and compare its name to the whatsapp package name.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)) {
  if (packageInfo.packageName.equals(“com.whatsapp")) {
    return true;
  }
}
```