# Check whether whatsapp installed or not for particular mobile number

Tags: android, whatsapp

how to check whether user has whatsapp installed or not???
I want app like whenever I click on users number it should display message whether that user has whatsapp or not...
please help me.I have listview of contacts info means name and number..I want to check whether that particular number has whatsapp installed or not on click of listview item????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if application is installed - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)

Comment: I have listview of contacts info means name and number..I want to check whether that particular number has whatsapp installed or not on click of listview item????

Answer (score 1):

Use packagemanager to get the installed app info:
for whatsapp package name is com.whatsapp

```
boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");  //the method returns boolean value here

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");  just call the method wherever needed

Comment: I want to check whether whatsapp installed for that particular number or not???Will this method remain same in this condition also??

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isInstalled(String packageName) {
    if (StringUtils.equalsNull(packageName)) {
        return false;
    }
    PackageManager pm = ContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> list = pm
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (PackageInfo p : list) {
        if (packageName.equals(p.packageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```