# Make android app NOT be able to be found by other apps?

Tags: android

I know it might sound weird, but I wanna protect my clients by not allowing other apps to know my clients have installed my app?

I know there is a way to read the installed app like [Check if application is installed - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)

So my problem is if there is anyway to make those api doesn't work to your app? so it can make your app like hidden to other apps?

BTW, just wanna clarifying that this problem is meaningful because you don't wanna Facebook app or its 3rd advertisement app know you have something like a porn app in phone.

Answer (score 1):

> So my problem is if there is anyway to make those api doesn't work to your app?

No.

> so it can make your app like hidden to other apps?

Sorry. Malware authors would love this.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't need to be malware. System(Android) or users can see it. I just wanna the other app and its third-party libs unable to see my app.