# Is there possibility of adding whatsApp option in my application?

Tags: android, email, whatsapp

I am developing an Android based application.

1. In my app **communication** between users plays a vital role. My app has 
   built-in **E-mail** options as a primary source of communication and I wants 
   to add **WhatsApp** option too.
2. Is there a way to add WhatsApp option inside my app which when chosen opens 
   open **WhatsApp** Application? If yes, I would love to know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check if [WhatsApp is installed on the device.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android) The package name for the WhatsApp app is `com.whatsapp`.

If it's installed, then you can use [an explicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleExplicit) to automatically take the user to the app to send a message.

*You can not under any circumstances control how the user uses WhatApp.  It merely opens the app for use.  You may be able to guide a user to a particular contact, but that's going to be part of WhatsApp's api and is not guaranteed.*

If it is not installed, then you can either remove the option from view since it simply can not be used, or [send them to the play store to download it.](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html#android-app)

WhatsApp, to my knowledge, does not have an open API, so you can not directly integrate the service in to your app.  You'll always have to be taken out of it.

Alternatively, you can also send the [message as an SMS through an implicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging).  This will allow the user to use whatever messaging app they want so long as they handle SMS.