# Check if 3rd party app has been installed?

Tags: java, c#, android, ios, swift

You built a mobile app and your mobile app relies on a 3rd party app.

Is it possible for your mobile app to find out if the required 3rd party app has been installed or not? (If not then prompt the user to install the required app.)

Comment: You would need the package name of the specific app to check if it is installed in the device. follow below answer it'll work.

Comment: Note that if your app requires another app to be installed in order to run it will be rejected by Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if a particular pacakage has been installed by using a `PackageManager`. You can include the code to fetch the package inside the `catch` statement.

```java
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check the following answer for further explanation

[Check if application is installed - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752202/check-if-application-is-installed-android)