# Can we able to get installation result from Google Play page in Android?

Tags: android

Here is my question,

- I need to redirect the user to specific app page (Google play page) from **Page_One.Java**. (Implemented)
- The user successfully install that application from Google Play page, now it returns to previous page.(Implemented)
- Now i need to get the response in **Page_One.java**, whether the app installation is success or failed. Is it possible to get the installation status?

Answer (score 2):

You can check with the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) if the application has been installed or not.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016624/2015318) you can find a working code that helps to find out if the application is properly installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a broadcast receiver detecting a package added action like this :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.InstalledReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then declare a broadcast receiver class

```
public class InstalledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String installedPackage = intent.getDataString();
        //Uri like package://com.example.myapp
    }
}
```

In the onReceive method you will know if it was the correct application. However I am not sure if you can get the status on failure

Comment: may i know we can't use startActivityForResult(); instead of startActivity();

Comment: startActivityForResult requires the Activity you are calling to manually set a result. I am not sure on how you call the Google Play Page (maybe with the standard `android.action.VIEW` ) but I don't think it will return a result.

Comment: I called the market like this, Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       marketUri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(marketIntent);

Comment: That is what I thought. I believe, after reading your question once again that the answer provided by StarsSky is the most suitable with your needs.