# Android : How to install a set of apps through a single app

Tags: android, assets, aapt

I have a set of applications built for a specific company.
I want these applications to be installed together in a single main app interface.
When the main application icon is clicked, the user will be provided with the set of all company apps and then he can choose to run the app that is necessary.
Any applications built in future for the company should be added to these group of apps when installed.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not possible (if you wana do this quaietly) ... of course you can "unpack" the apks from assets/raw(or download from cloud) to the storage and start install the apk from there(bazillion examples - even here on SO) but ... but still user will be asked about confirmation for every apk

Answer (score 1):

> I have a set of applications built for a specific company. I want these applications to be installed together in a single main app interface.

Your options are:

1. Rewrite this to be a single application.
2. Remove the "to be installed together" requirement.

You can certainly arrange to have a "main app" prompt the user to install each of the other applications, one at a time, but this would not seem to fulfil the "to be installed together" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you stand with the Google Play terms of services regarding "wrapper apps" but you could easily use an intent to launch the Google Play app. Paraphrased from the [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.yourcompany.yourapp"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This would allow you, for example, to have a set of buttons, each linking to an app. You could then detect whether each app is installed and display a tick indicator or whatever (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016624/4887407 for details on app install detection).

(I should point out that you would need to update the main app when a new "child" app was released. The search capabilities of the market URLs seem to be limited to simple strings, so it doesn't look like you could link to a "collection" of your company's apps in Google Play).

Comment: These applications are exclusively for the company employees.
They will not be used for any other purpose or uploaded anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can launch intents from main app, but when you install a new app you have to update the main one with a new list of intents.